# How to Removing fields from the Media Uploader/Gallery on a Custom Post Type Edit Page

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, uploads, media, media-library

[This post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45562/removing-fields-from-the-media-uploader-gallery/45581#45581) shows how to remove unwanted fields from the media uploader. It works great, but I want to limit it to a custom-post-type and I can't seem to figure out how to do it.  I've tried the following code, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
add_filter('attachment_fields_to_edit', 'remove_media_upload_fields', 10000, 2);
function remove_media_upload_fields( $form_fields, $post ) {
global $my_admin_page;
$screen = get_current_screen();
if ( 'slider' == $screen->post_type ){

unset( $form_fields['image-size'] );
unset( $form_fields['post_excerpt'] );
unset( $form_fields['url'] );
unset( $form_fields['image_url'] );
unset( $form_fields['align'] );

}

return $form_fields;
}
```

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Thanks,

Moshe

Comment: Please update your question to explain what fields you want to remove from a custom post type, how that post type is registered, and anything else you've tried. I get the feeling that the code snippet you included isn't relevant, but maybe I just don't understand the question.

Answer (score 3):

The current screen doesn't appear to be set when that filter is run, so you cannot use that. Also, the `$post` actually refers to the attachment, not the post - so we can't get the post typ fro that either....

So looking at the source code: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.2/wp-admin/includes/media.php

The filter you are using is called by `get_attachment_fields_to_edit`, tracing this - we find its called by `get_media_item`.

Looking at `get_media_time`, it unfortunately does not pass the post ID or object. However, it does have:

```
$current_post_id = !empty( $_GET['post_id'] ) ? (int) $_GET['post_id'] : 0;
```

This indicates that the only way of getting the post ID (and thus post type), is to grab it from `$_GET`. It would be nicer if this was passed as along with the `$args` array that is defined then.

So:

```
add_filter('attachment_fields_to_edit', 'remove_media_upload_fields', 10000, 2);
function remove_media_upload_fields( $form_fields, $post ) {
    $post_id = !empty( $_GET['post_id'] ) ? (int) $_GET['post_id'] : 0;
    $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);

    if( 'slider' == $post_type ){
        // remove unnecessary fields
        unset( $form_fields['image-size'] );
        unset( $form_fields['post_excerpt'] );
        unset( $form_fields['post_content'] );
        unset( $form_fields['url'] );
        unset( $form_fields['image_url'] );
        unset( $form_fields['align'] );
    }
    return $form_fields;
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to say thank-you - this worked exactly as I wanted.