# Remove fields on media uploader for custom page type - not working for "From Computer" or "From Url" tabs?

Tags: custom-post-types, uploads, media-library

[This code works](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51546/how-to-removing-fields-from-the-media-uploader-gallery-on-a-custom-post-type-edi) for me if I go to upload a file and choose the **Gallery** or **Media Library** tabs then it correctly hides elements on the page.

If I go to the **From Computer** or **From URL** tabs, nothing is hidden!

If I take out the if statement then it works. I can't see why it shouldn't be working on these 2 tabs as the URLs are the same apart from the tab parameter and the if statement is only checking the post_id:

**Gallery tab** works:
/wp-admin/media-upload.php?post_id=4&type=image&tab=gallery

**From Computer** tab doesn't work:
/wp-admin/media-upload.php?post_id=4&type=image&tab=type

**Edit**

On pages using my custom post type I am passing through the parameter of type=image to the media uploader. For 2 of the tabs my code within the if statement is not being executed:

[image: 2 tabs still showing all information]

The other 2 tabs on the media uploader popup do what I want:

[image: Code running correctly]

If I have the if statement as:

```
if ($_GET['type'] == 'image')
```

Then it still doesnt trigger the code on **From Computer** or **Gallery Tab** so I can't rely on the querystring?

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not getting your goal... What are you referring as "***Remove fields on media uploader on specific page only***"? - In what cases are you expecting the fields to be removed? - Only in *one* specific page? Or for every post/page? Or only for image attachments? - - And this last doubt arises from your update...

Comment: I've corrected the title and edited the question some more, sorry for the confusion!

Comment: No problem, it's just a matter of making the Q&A better formed so it'll help future visitors, and at the same time don't fall in the "too localized" category. So, you only need this in your CPT? And no, the query string doesn't get passed from one tab to another... Somewhere I have a code that deals with this. Will check this option and grabbing a `$post_type` alternative.

Comment: The query string `type=image` refers to a [Custom Post Type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Types), right? If so, the updated version of the code should work for this question... Just out of curiosity, how are you injecting this query string when calling the Media Upload iframe?

Comment: `type=image` comes from my onclick event of the insert image button I have `tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?post_id='+postId+'&amp;type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true');`
The code all works now apart from on a normal post page, on the media library tab it runs the code within the if statement if a photo was uploaded from my custom page type because the parent post type will be **movie**. I can't see a way around that though. If only the **From Computer** tab would have access just like the media library tab does.. :(

Comment: Kevin, the solution is in the comments of the code and in the code itself. You have to play with `$library_tab` and `'post' == $post_type` to fine tune your desired setup. Good luck! :)

Comment: Ah, all works now! Thanks!

if((!$library_tab || isset($_GET['image'])) && ('movie' == $post_type || 'movie' == $attachment_post_type )){

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Version 1

```
Deals with filtering based on Post ID
```

#### *From Computer* tab

we need to retrieve the `$attachment_parent_id`:

```
add_filter('attachment_fields_to_edit', 'wpse_53600_remove_media_upload_fields', 10000, 2);
function wpse_53600_remove_media_upload_fields( $form_fields, $post ) {
    $our_page_id = 4;
    $post_id = !empty( $_GET['post_id'] ) ? (int) $_GET['post_id'] : 0;
    $attachment_parent_id = !empty($post->post_parent) ? $post->post_parent : 0;

    if( $post_id == $our_page_id || $attachment_parent_id == $our_page_id ){
        // Please, check VERSION 2 for full code
    }
    return $form_fields;
}
```

---

#### *From URL* tab

looks like another approach is necessary:

```
add_filter('type_url_form_media', 'wpse_53600_remove_from_url_fields', 10, 1);
function wpse_53600_remove_from_url_fields($html) {
    $our_page_id = 4;
    $post_id = !empty( $_GET['post_id'] ) ? (int) $_GET['post_id'] : 0;

    if( $post_id != $our_page_id)
        return $html;

    // Used to hide the unwanted table rows
    $display_none = 'style="display:none"';

    $html = '';// Please, check VERSION 2 for full code

    return $html;
}
```

---

---

## Version 2

```
Deals with filtering based on Post Type
```

```
/*
 * Remove extra fields from Media Upload tabs based on the Post Type
 * In this example, it is a CPT named 'movie', but it could be 'post' or 'page'
 *
 * http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/53600/12615
 */

add_filter('type_url_form_media', 'wpse_53600_remove_from_url_fields', 10, 1);
add_filter('attachment_fields_to_edit', 'wpse_53600_remove_media_upload_fields', 10000, 2);

/* FILTERS THE 'FROM COMPUTER' TAB */
function wpse_53600_remove_from_url_fields($html) {

    $post_id = !empty( $_GET['post_id'] ) ? (int) $_GET['post_id'] : 0;
    $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);

    if( 'movie' != $post_type)
        return $html;

    // Used to hide the unwanted table rows
    $display_none = 'style="display:none"';

    $html = <<<HTML
     <p class="media-types">
        <label><input type="radio" name="media_type" value="image" id="image-only" checked='checked' /> Image</label> &nbsp; &nbsp; <label><input type="radio" name="media_type" value="generic" id="not-image" /> Audio, Video, or Other File</label>
    </p> 
    <table class="describe ">
        <tbody> 
            <tr> <th valign="top" scope="row" class="label" style="width:130px;"> <span class="alignleft"><label for="src">URL</label></span> <span class="alignright"><abbr id="status_img" title="required" class="required">*</abbr></span> </th> <td class="field"><input id="src" name="src" value="" type="text" aria-required="true" onblur="addExtImage.getImageData()" /></td> </tr>
            <tr> <th valign="top" scope="row" class="label"> <span class="alignleft"><label for="title">Title</label></span> <span class="alignright"><abbr title="required" class="required">*</abbr></span> </th> <td class="field"><input id="title" name="title" value="" type="text" aria-required="true" /></td> </tr>
            <tr class="not-image" {$display_none}><td></td><td><p class="help">Link text, e.g. &#8220;Ransom Demands (PDF)&#8221;</p></td></tr>
            <tr class="image-only" {$display_none}> <th valign="top" scope="row" class="label"> <span class="alignleft"><label for="alt">Alternate Text</label></span> </th> <td class="field"><input id="alt" name="alt" value="" type="text" aria-required="true" /> <p class="help">Alt text for the image, e.g. &#8220;The Mona Lisa&#8221;</p></td> </tr>
            <tr class="image-only" {$display_none}> <th valign="top" scope="row" class="label"> <span class="alignleft"><label for="caption">Image Caption</label></span> </th> <td class="field"><input id="caption" name="caption" value="" type="text" /></td> </tr>
            <tr class="align image-only" {$display_none}> <th valign="top" scope="row" class="label"><p><label for="align">Alignment</label></p></th> <td class="field"> <input name="align" id="align-none" value="none" onclick="addExtImage.align='align'+this.value" type="radio" checked="checked" /> <label for="align-none" class="align image-align-none-label">None</label> <input name="align" id="align-left" value="left" onclick="addExtImage.align='align'+this.value" type="radio" /> <label for="align-left" class="align image-align-left-label">Left</label> <input name="align" id="align-center" value="center" onclick="addExtImage.align='align'+this.value" type="radio" /> <label for="align-center" class="align image-align-center-label">Center</label> <input name="align" id="align-right" value="right" onclick="addExtImage.align='align'+this.value" type="radio" /> <label for="align-right" class="align image-align-right-label">Right</label> </td> </tr>
            <tr class="image-only" {$display_none}> <th valign="top" scope="row" class="label"> <span class="alignleft"><label for="url">Link Image To:</label></span> </th> <td class="field"><input id="url" name="url" value="" type="text" /><br /> <button type="button" class="button" value="" onclick="document.forms[0].url.value=null">None</button> <button type="button" class="button" value="" onclick="document.forms[0].url.value=document.forms[0].src.value">Link to image</button> <p class="help">Enter a link URL or click above for presets.</p></td> </tr>
            <tr class="image-only"> <td></td> <td> <input type="button" class="button" id="go_button" style="color:#bbb;" onclick="addExtImage.insert()" value="Insert into Post" /> </td> </tr>
            <tr class="not-image"> <td></td> <td> <input type="submit" name="insertonlybutton" id="insertonlybutton" class="button" value="Insert into Post" /> </td> </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
HTML;

    return $html;
}

/* FILTERS THE REST OF THE TABS */
function wpse_53600_remove_media_upload_fields( $form_fields, $post ) {

    $post_id = !empty( $_GET['post_id'] ) ? (int) $_GET['post_id'] : 0;
    $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);

    $attachment_parent_id = !empty($post->post_parent) ? $post->post_parent : 0;
    $attachment_post_type = get_post_type($attachment_parent_id);

    /* 
     * This conditional will also filter the attachments in the Library tab that fall under the 'movie' CPT
     * Use the following to filter the Library tab: 
     *
     * $library_tab = ( isset($_GET['tab']) && 'library' == $_GET['tab']) ? true : false;
     *
     */ 
    if( 'movie' == $post_type || 'movie' == $attachment_post_type ){
        // remove unnecessary fields
        unset( $form_fields['image-size'] );
        unset( $form_fields['post_excerpt'] );
        unset( $form_fields['post_content'] );
        unset( $form_fields['url'] );
        unset( $form_fields['image_url'] );
        unset( $form_fields['align'] );
    }

    return $form_fields;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! What dynamic value should $our_page_id be though? $post_id is the page that has the link to bring up the popup media uploader so I can't think of any other variable.

Comment: @KevinUK - well, in the question's title you refer to *one* specific page. 35 was the ID of the page (it could be a post) I was testing. I've updated the answer with the value you provide in the question's content. Is this it?

Comment: I've updated my question. It's being called from any page so I was using the querystring but that doesn't seem to be called on the 2 tabs I have the problem with.