# Custom Text in Media Uploader in a Theme Options Page

Tags: uploads, theme-options, thickbox

I want to replace the media uploader thickbox text only if it's used in the theme options page. If it is used in the Post then I don't want to make any changes.

I am trying the following code, but this will change media uploader text in the post as well.
How can I make it to change text only in the theme options page?

```
add_filter("attribute_escape", "myfunction", 10, 2);
function myfunction($safe_text, $text) {
    return str_replace("Insert into Post", "Use this image", $text);
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to WPSE! Please, search before posting a Question. Possible duplicate of [Rename the insert button in media upload window](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26585/rename-the-insert-button-in-media-upload-window). Also, read this [Stack FAQ](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq) to better understand its mechanics, thanks!

Comment: @brasofilo the link you mention is not duplicate of my question. If you can read my question again, I know how to change the text, the only problem is how to change text only if the media window is used in the options page (not in any type of post).

Comment: Sorry, casper, too fast to read = misreading. Made few improvements to the Q and removed the down vote.

Answer (score 1):

This is a short version of what I do in [one](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/many-tips-together/) of my plugins.
I copied this behavior from the plugin [Advanced Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields) (some versions ago, donnow how it proceeds now).

1) When calling the thickbox, add a custom query var (`mtt_type` in this case):

```
tb_show('{$mtt_title}', 'media-upload.php?type=image&amp;mtt_type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true');
```

2) Print scripts in `media-upload.php` to modify the text. Code not tested:

```
add_action('admin_head-media-upload-popup','wpse_59984_script_enqueuer');

function wpse_59984_script_enqueuer() {
    if( !isset($_GET['mtt_type'] )
        return;

    // HIDE MANY ELEMENTS   
    ?>
        <style>
        #media-upload-header #sidemenu li#tab-type_url, tr.post_excerpt, tr.post_content, tr.url, tr.align, tr.image_alt, tr.post_title.form-required {display: none !important}
        }
        </style>
    <?php

    // REFRESH UPLOAD SCREEN EVERY HALF SECOND TO CHANGE THE BUTTON NAMES
    // Only happens in the Upload Tab
    $tab = isset( $_GET['tab'] ) ? $_GET['tab'] : "type";
    if ( 'type' == $tab ) 
        $refresh = 'var mtt_t = setInterval(function(){
            $("#media-items").each(setButtonNames); 
            $("p.savebutton").css("display", "none");
        }, 500);';
    else 
        $refresh = '';

    // BUTTON NAME
    $select = __("Select Image", 'mtt');

    //CHANGE BUTTON NAMES
   ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function setButtonNames() {
            jQuery(this).find('.savesend .button').val('{$select}');
        }
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $('#media-items').each(setButtonNames);
            <?php echo $refresh; ?>
        });
        </script>
    <?php
}
```